# VPN Server for Mac (Without OS X Server)

Tags: macros, osx-lion, vpn

Is there any way to set up my mini (osx-lion) to be a VPN server?

I searched this in google, and got two solution:

They are [iVPN](http://macserve.org.uk/projects/ivpn/) and [VPN Server Configurator](http://www.greenworldsoft.com/product-vpn-server-help.html), but they are not free.

I would like to do this for free, is it possible?  and I am not running OS X server. Also I am behind a router (so there is only one external IP address for 8 computers).

I want to use PPTP.

Is there any solution?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't invest time, update to MAC OS X Server which comes with a full OpenVPN server

Comment: Thanks, but not alternative for Lion-osx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac is unix, so you can use most of the linux vpn server, like pptpd